# Setting external IP for Citrix Web Interface

Tags: citrix, xenapp

I have a Citrix Web Interface (as part of XenApp 6.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2) that is behind a NAT, I can access the web interface fine (via both SSL and standard port 80) but when I go to launch a application that connection is still being made over the server's internal IP address.

How do I configure the web interface to default to the external IP address of the box instead of its internal LAN IP?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, unless your XenApp servers also have internet facing IP's. Once the web interface has dealt with the authentication it doesn't do any tunnelling, so the client has to be able to connect directly to the XenApp server.

The alternative is the Citrix Access Gateway or the Citrix Secure Gateway. The latter sits on top of the Web Interface and is designed to do exactly what you require.